# Grails: IllegalArgumentException: Queue configuration must be a list of maps

Tags: spring-boot, grails, rabbitmq

In a newly generated Grails application containing RabbitMQ when I try to start the server I get the following exception:

`ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  - Application run failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Queue configuration must be a list of maps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `application.yml` and in the `rabbitmq` section remove the line beginning with the `queues:` key

```
rabbitmq:
  enabled: true
  queues:
  exchanges:
    ....
```

becomes

```
rabbitmq:
  enabled: true
  exchanges:
    ....
```

An empty value is not allowed for `queues`. Now the server starts properly.